# "There are currently no communities in this view." message in Sharepoint 2013 Community Portal2

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created 2 community sites, and then a Community Portal, every things is OK except, in community portal home page, it keeps showing "There are currently no communities in this view." while there should be 2 portals there.

p.s. I though there might be some threshold for showing as active blog, since I have had some discussions in the portals to make them active, but nothing is changed.

How can I overcome this issue?

[image]

Comment: You might want to try the [SharePoint Stack Exchange Network](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AstroCB Thanks I have solved my problem, but it's good for next problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was about search service application indexes. I set crawling rules and content via Central Administration --> Manage service applications --> Search Service Applications. Then I reset the index and re-crawl.

[image]

Thanks everybody